# Send-MailMessage shortens lines in message when triggered by Task Scheduler and breaks FullNames

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, sendmail

I'm not able to find a reason why **lines in emails are shortened when it is triggered by Task Scheduler**(lines aren't shortened when the script is executed manualy from ISE!). I'd like to pass FullName to email and use it as link to document (when the path and file doesn't contain spaces, the link works great).

[image: End of lines are missing]

If I use "format-list" instead of "format-table" it looks better (even when triggered by Task Scheduler) and I have to add parameter "$body = $newdoc | Out-String -Width 255" to prevent breaking lines - but space in filenames still breaks links:

[image]

Next thing is the FullName contains spaces - I tried many ways (like $variable.replace; $var = $var -replace " ","` ", etc.)

```
#date and time formating
$culture = Get-Culture
$culture.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = 'HH:mm'
$culture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = 'dd-MM-yyyy'
Set-Culture $culture

#find files changed during last hour, sort descending
$newdoc = get-childitem -File -Path \\ottm09itoms01\OTA-IT_Operators\ -Recurse | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)} | sort lastwritetime -Descending | Format-table -Property LastWriteTime, fullname

$body = $newdoc | Out-String
$enc  = New-Object System.Text.utf8encoding
Send-MailMessage -From $sender -To $receiver2 -Subject "Documents updated" -body $body -Encoding $enc -SmtpServer $SMTPserver
```

Comment: As far as I know, there's nothing you can do to force `Format-Table` to not truncate data unless you use the `-wrap` switch, but that would obviously break your links. Have you considered using `Format-List` instead?

Comment: @Nacimota - so I changed it to "format-list" - it looks may be even better, but it breaks long lines now - please see updated question. thanks

Comment: I've posted an answer addressing what I think might be the actual issue; let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some digging, I suspect the problem is your use of `Out-String` which truncates output based on the `-width` parameter, which you have left unspecified. To quote [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-string):

> `-width`
>   Specifies the number of characters in each line of output. Any additional characters are truncated, not wrapped. If you omit this parameter, the width is determined by the characteristics of the host program. The default value for the Windows PowerShell console is 80 (characters).

In other words, when you run this script in the ISE `Out-String` probably sets the width to whatever the buffer width of the ISE is, but when Task Scheduler runs it, it uses the default 80 character width.

So basically just add `-width 120` (or the value of your choosing) to your `Out-String` and see if that fixes the problem.

---

To fix the links breaking on whitespace you might have to manually generate some HTML for them using `-replace`. Something like:

```
$body = $body -replace '(\\\\.*[^\s])','<a href="$1">$1</a>'
$body = $body.trim() -replace "`n","<br>`n"
```

This assumes that all your paths are UNC paths (i.e., paths starting with `\\`). You'd then need to throw the `-BodyAsHtml` on your `Send-MailMessage` command. This is kind of thrown together and I'm sure there's probably a better way of doing things, but it *should* work.

Comment: Great - the lines are not broken now, but the spaces in filenames still breaks links. Have you got any idea about it?

Comment: @joeedit I've updated my answer with an idea for fixing the links; let me know if it works for you.

Comment: correction - this works -> **$body = $body -replace '(\\\\.*[^\s])','"$1"'**